# Remove uninstalled apps that show up on Windows Search

Tags: windows, windows-10, search

When using the Start Menu to search something that has been uninstalled, it still shows up there. It does nothing when pressed, and right-clicking doesn't work, even after reinstalling the app.

The apps are present for all users.

I tried searching for the links in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` and `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`, but didn't find anything.

I also deleted the search index and disabled the indexation service; it had no effect.

As a last resort, I tried nuking every path/key that contained the application's name in the registry. I thought I was onto something when I found multiple infracting apps under a certain key, but deleting them proved useless (also, I'm sorry I can't find the key's name; it was something of a non-UWP app listing for the start menu, specifically).

Comment: Try CCleaner to clean cache and registry.

Comment: @Biswa - Author already tried that.

Comment: Did you reboot in the process? Many uninstalls require a reboot to remove last traces.

Comment: @Biswa I missed listing CCleaner, but I did run it.

Comment: @LPChip I did reboot multiple times after trying each method, but it's always still there. The issue is, even when Skype is installed and there is a proper link in the `Programs` folder, if I press the Windows key and type Skype, the search result simply doesn't start it. Only if I manually scroll down to the Skype folder in the start menu and use the link inside it I can get it to start.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure 'Enable context menus and dragging and dropping"  Is checked in the Start Menu and TaskBar options.

Right click task bar > Properties > Start Menu Tab > Customize

Comment: Why did this get voted down? If he has issues right clicking and using the Context menu, he needs to double check that it didn't get unchecked for some reason.